# Cannot find name '$' in component.ts

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I got error:'Cannot find name '$' in component' on compile time of angular web-app. When i used `const $ : any = '';` then solved error but getting a another error in browsers console: 'core.js:1440 ERROR TypeError: $ is not a function' and also datatable not working when used `const $ : any = '';`.

Below is my code of users component. This component is used for list of users into datatable.

users.component.ts

```
import {DataService} from './../services/data.service';
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {API_ENDPOINT} from '../app.module';
import {Response} from '@angular/http/src/static_response';


const $: any = '';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-users',
    templateUrl: './users.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

    private url = API_ENDPOINT + '/admin_api/users';
    private users: any;

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.get(this.url)
            .subscribe(responce => {
                this.users = responce.data.users;
                if (this.users) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        var oTable1 = $('#sample-table-2').dataTable({
                            "aoColumns": [
                                {"bSortable": false},
                                null, null, null, null, null,
                                {"bSortable": false}
                            ],
                        });
                    }, 3000);
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery somewhere?>

Comment: I added external js of jquery into index.html file

Comment: They try `npm install @types/jquery`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- In the console First install jQuery

```
npm install --save jquery
```

- And install  jQuery Definition

```
npm install -D @types/jquery
```

- call your jquery in your componenet

```
import {DataService} from './../services/data.service';
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {API_ENDPOINT} from '../app.module';
import {Response} from '@angular/http/src/static_response';
import * as $ from 'jquery';// import Jquery here    
.
.
your code
.
.
```

- And don't need use `const $: any = '';`, You should remove this declaration.

Comment: But i already added external js of jquery into index.html file

Comment: But where you import this in your component. `const $: any = '';` is just a variable.

Comment: I used declare var $: any; instead of import * as $ from 'jquery'; and now it is working..

Comment: @MandipVora Yeah! that is the proper solution for all .  :) good luck

Comment: I faced another issue for datatable, when i removed settimeout then datatable doesn't load data, any solution for that?

Answer (score 5):

I have seen similar and solution which worked for me was,

1. Install jQuery

   `npm install jquery --save`
2. Install type jQuery

   `npm install @types/jquery`
3. Import it into your module

   `//THis is important
   import * as $ from 'jquery';`

Hope this will help!

Comment: I just followed your steps, now getting error for datatable in console:'$(...).dataTable is not a function'

Comment: I used declare var $: any; instead of import * as $ from 'jquery'; and now it is working..

Comment: I faced another issue for datatable, when i removed settimeout then datatable doesn't load data, any solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

*install jQuery*

> npm install --save jquery

**And install jQuery Definition**

> npm install -D @types/jquery

** than include jquery in component like this **

> import * as $ from jquery

Comment: Note that I had to do "import $ from jquery" instead.